# How can i solve this query in sql oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

It's an exercise that is not solved in the book in which I am studying. 
The goal is to find the seller who has had the highest number of sales per month, 
during all the months for which there is registered information. The problem is that I do not know how to divide tuples into periods of one month.

First table is:

```
Table Sellers

Id_seller
Name_Product
```

And the other one is:

```
Table Product

Name_Product
View_datetime
Budget
```

**What did i do?**

I made this query:

```
SELECT id_seller FROM(SELECT id_seller, COUNT(id_seller)
FROM SELLERS INNER JOIN PRODUCT
ON SELLERS.name_product = PRODUCT.name_product
GROUP BY id_seller HAVING COUNT(id_seller)>= 1
ORDER BY 2 DESC)
WHERE ROWNUM = 1;
```

The query returns me the seller that most sales has done, but not "per month since there are records" as the statement asks. Any ideas? I'm so lost...

The idea is to compare the total sales of each salesman in this month (sysdate), with those of a month ago, two months ago ... so long as there are older records. And get the maximum from each seller. And then you print the seller with more sales from the previous list. If a seller sells 400 products this month(April, the sysdate), but another seller sold in October last year 500, the result would be the second seller . That's what I do not know how to do.

Thanks ^^

Comment: Could you share some sample data and the result you're trying to get for it?

Comment: @Mureinik im not sure what you mean, the result im trying to get is what the statement asks (?). 
The problem is that I do not know how to divide into one-month periods each of the sales, group them by seller, and get the salesman that has made more sales per month since there are records.

Comment: What Mureinik is asking is "what is the structure of your input data" and "what is the exact output format you desire." For example, for the input data - what do you have? A table with columns for salesman, date of transaction, and amount of sale? The date being any date within any month? Or is the input data summarized by month already? These are things we can't "guess" without seeing your sample data, or else a very long and detailed explanation from you.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this query

`select MonthName, id_seller, max(TotalSales) from (
select to_char(sysdate, 'Month') MonthName, sellers.id_seller, count(sellers.id_seller) TotalSales
from sellers inner join product
on sellers.name_product = product.name_product
group by to_char(view_datetime, 'Month'), sellers.id_seller
) tab
group by MonthName, id_seller`

Comment: It returns me the total number of sales of each seller, but only of the month of April (sysdate). The idea is to compare the total of this month with those of a month ago, two months ago ... so long as there are older records. And get the maximum. @jose

Comment: My mistake. I have modified the query with view_datetime in group by clause. This will return month wise highest sales by seller id. You could then have your pl/sql to iterate through the recordset and get the comparison

Answer (score 0):

There are a few points to make...

- The tables are weird. I assume your table `sellers` would better be called `sales`, right?
- In this example,  `having count... >= 1` is a no-op. Count could only be 0 if there were no rows at all, in which case there would be no row in the group- by output. You can just leave this count away, here.
- To get the sales per month, just add the month to the `group by`. I.e. `group by id_seller,  To_date(view_datetime,'YYYYMM')`.

Comment: I didnt explain it well...The idea is to compare the total sales of each salesman in this month (sysdate), with those of a month ago, two months ago ... so long as there are older records. And get the maximum from each seller. And then you print the seller with more sales from the previous list. If a seller sells 400 products this month(April, the sysdate), but another seller sold in October last year 500, the result would be the second seller . That's what I do not know how to do. @AnoE

Comment: For that, first group as shown above, then group the answer again (by month) and pick the seller with the maximum sales.

Comment: i'm really trying to do it, but dont resolve it, can you ilustrate it with an example pls?